# UV/Vis spectroscopy transition reference

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, reference-request, spectrophotometry

There are mainly fundamental transitions happening during excitation and UV/Vis spectroscopy (as n- > σ* ,π->π* ,n- > π ,..).  I am looking for a good reference that shows these transitions for molecules (for example shows n- > σ* for acetone , π- > π* for benzene,... ).

Actually I am talking about tables. I can do guesswork for most of the molecules based on their structures but definitely I need references for publication.

**Update:** Mostly interested in these molecules: Acetone, Acetaldehyde , Benzene , Naphthalene, Anthracene , Methylene Blue, Phenanthrene , 1-Butanol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a number of resources that may be of use for your research.

The UCLA website presents tables and data in their webpage [Theory of Ultraviolet-Visible (UV-Vis) Spectroscopy](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~bacher/UV-vis/uv_vis_tetracyclone.html.html), including reference tables of common functional groups, aromatics and compounds often used in the laboratory.  (Many compounds you listed are in the tables).

A reference that may be of use is [Spectroscopy of Organic Compounds](http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/eprints/publication_11_8282_250.pdf) (Kumar, 2006) which include several tables that include information of the compounds you list.

The book [Spectroscopy of Organic Compounds](https://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=QWq47QClOM0C&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=UV-Visible%20Spectroscopy%20of%20Organic%20Compounds&ots=kJ2V9ub4a9&sig=6oqeNZYzlvxSC2eg8RaXfwlAZnE#v=onepage&q=UV-Visible%20Spectroscopy%20of%20Organic%20Compounds&f=false) (Kalsi, 2007), from page 12 provide several tables of information related to your listed organic compounds, including details of the electronic transitions. The chapter "Ultraviolet (UV) and Visible Spectroscopy" (starting page 9) has a subsection "The Designation of Various Transitions" which details the electronic transitions using examples in context (from page 11, summarised in a diagram on page 12).  Examples of solvents are discussed from page 23 onwards.  (All available online).

Transitions are explored in a bit of detail in chapter 4.3 of the UC Davis ChemWiki The Dynamic Chemistry E-textbook, [Section 4.3: Ultraviolet and visible spectroscopy](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_With_a_Biological_Emphasis/Chapter_04%3A_Structure_Determination_I/Section_4.3%3A_Ultraviolet_and_visible_spectroscopy)